# Laravel 7 HTTP Client - Unable to send POST request with `body`

Tags: laravel, http, request, guzzle, laravel-7

Using Laravel 7.6 and it's built-in HTTP Client.

I'm trying to send a simple POST request with `body` in Raw JSON format to my other domain but no luck:

```
$response = Http::post('https://example.com', [
    'body' => '{ test: 1 }'
]);
```

I get 400 Bad Request - Client error - because my server expects `body` as a mandatory.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
$response = Http:post('http://example.com/', [
   'foo' =>   'bar'
]);
```

Or this

```
$response = Http::withHeaders([
 'User-Agent' => 'Some Agent',
])->asForm()->post('http://www.example.com/', [
  'foo' => 'bar',
]);
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this, in my case this should works.

```
$response = Http::withHeaders(['Content-Type' => 'application/json'])
    ->send('POST', 'https://example.com', [
        'body' => '{ test: 1 }'
    ])->json();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same scenario: I have a json string I want to send to an endpoint.

To acomplish this, I just transformed the string using:

```
$dataArray = json_decode(
    { "test": "1" },
    true
);
```

Then, I called the ->post() like this:

```
)->post(
    env('APP_URL') . '/api/webhook',
    $dataArray
);
```

This way, it just sends the json string, without adding any root elements.

Comment: Your `json_encode()` is not valid PHP, and will throw a parse error.